# How to create a sub array of objects in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have one object array with 100 objects.
I created one sub of the above mentioned array with 10 objects.
Now i want the remaining 90 objects as a new array.
What is the java code to do that?

Comment: Check out the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

Here, I can see you need help...

```
Object[] original;

Object[] rest = Arrays.copyOfRange(original, 10, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what JDK you are using

- **jdk > 1.5**

  `Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`

Documentation can be fond [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

- **jdk < 1.5**

  ```
  System.arraycopy(Object[] srcArray, int srcStartIndex, Object[] destArray, int dstStartIndex, int lengthOfIndicesToBeCopied);
  ```

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).